# Checking whether a timestamp is 10 minutes old

Tags: java, datetime

I have a timestamp (`searchTimestamp`) which I need to check to see whether it is less than 10 minutes old or not:

```
long currentTimestamp = System.currentTimeMillis();

long searchTimestamp = getTheTimestampFromURL();// this also gives me back timestamp in 13 digit (1425506040493)

long difference = Math.abs(currentTimestamp - searchTimestamp);

System.out.println(difference);

if (difference > 10 * 60 * 1000) {
    System.out.println("timestamp is greater than 5 minutes old");
}
```

I have got the above code which is working fine. Is this the right way to do this or is there any better way?

`getTheTimestampFromURL` will always be older than the current timestamp in milliseconds.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Your description says that you want to check whether the `searchTimestamp` is less than 10 minutes old. Your code does something different, though.

Your code checks whether there's less than 10 minutes between the times (the difference is <= 10 minutes .... If the searchTimestamp is 2 minutes in the future, it will pass the test, if it is 9 minutes in the future, it will pass the test, and if it is 11 minutes in the future, it will ***fail*** the test.

Of interest, the math you use does a 10 minute check, but the message says *"greater than 5 minutes old."*

Your message should say: *"timestamp is older than 10 minutes, or more than 10 minutes in the future"*

So, changing your code to be what I think it should be, is a lot simpler than you would think.

What you want is for the `searchTimestamp` to have happened sometime after 10 minutes ago.... this is the way to do it:

```
private static final int TEN_MINUTES = 10 * 60 * 1000;
```

then, in your method:

```
long tenAgo = System.currentTimeMillis() - TEN_MINUTES;
if (searchTimestamp < tenAgo) {
    System.out.println("searchTimestamp is older than 10 minutes");
}
```

Answer (score 4):

joda-time is a very nice library that can overcome some of the shortfalls in the core Java Date/Time classes. For example:

```
DateTime now = new DateTime();

DateTime fromString = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyyyMMdd").parseDateTime(input);
DateTime fromDate = new DateTime(timeInMillis);
DateTime then = fromDate;

Interval interval = new Interval(then, now);
if (interval.toDuration().getStandardMinutes() > 10) {
    ...
}
```

I wouldn't use Math.abs(...) to bypass not knowing which way around to compare your timestamps. That's just lazy.

Also, 10, 60, etc. are magic numbers relating to time. joda-time has `DateTimeConstants.MILLIS_PER_MINUTE` if you must have the number, but for manipulating DateTimes you should be using functions rather than directly manipulating the millis. Core Java, you can use `TimeUnit.MINUTES.toMillis(10)`.

Comment: Why should one use a library for something that can be done native?

Answer (score -1):

To check if date is today, use Android utils library

> DateUtils.isToday(long timeInMilliseconds)

This utils class also offers human readable strings for relative times. For example,

> DateUtils.getRelativeTimeSpanString(long timeInMilliseconds) -> "42
>   minutes ago"

The are several parameters you can play with to define how precise the time span should be

Comment: Welcome on Code Review. The OP never talk about Android, so, I'm not sure your response could be helpful. (especially considering the posting date)